# SqLite not update in Anglurjs

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework, insert-update

We are need Update MobileNumber in DB and Then get Data form Server using Mobile Number but we don't have luck.We are tried like this

```
.controller('pETLoverSCtrl', function($scope,$cordovaSQLite,$http,$location,$window,BlankService) {
             $scope.sendNumber = function () {
 **//DB**
            var  db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB("SaveDOGDB.db");
            $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS UserInfo (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, MobileNumber INTEGER,UserName TEXT,UserPhoto BLOB,UserAddress TEXT,UserPinCode INTEGER,ServiceProvider TEXT,UserPassword TEXT)');
 //GET mobile number
           var MobileNumberGet = $scope.RegisterMobileNumber;
            alert(MobileNumberGet);
            alert("Update UserInfo SET MobileNumber="+MobileNumberGet+"");

            // execute INSERT statement with parameter
            $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, 'Update UserInfo SET MobileNumber='+MobileNumberGet+'')
            .then(function(result) {
                  console.log("Message updated successful, cheers!");
                  }, function(error) {
                  console.log("Error on saving: " + error.message);
                  })
**//Services** 
               $http({
                     method : "GET",
                     url : 'http://192.168.3.118:2244/api/Login/OTP?MobileNumber=' + MobileNumberGet
                     }).then(function mySucces(response) {

                                alert('suss'+response.data);
                         $location.path("/page2"); //two

                             }, function myError(response) {
                            alert(response);
                             console.log('ERR'+response.message);
                             });
            }
            });
```

Update and Get Data form Server both code fine .In different projects .But onces we placed same project in same file it's worked Please guide to us

We alreday add SqLite Plugin to our Project :using this

```
Cordova plugin add https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage.git
```

please guide to us and tell me what wrong with our code

Comment: hi, please format your source code and try to rewrite the text a little bit. It is very hard to understand... what means: "we need hit server using mobileNumber", "and get data from Services also", "two functionliys differently both are working fine but We need After update db"

Comment: @Meiko thanks for reply .1)We need update mobile number in db 
2)get data from server using mobile number 

our problem is update not working and get data from server also not working when we tried in same project 

if those are worked in differnt project

Comment: why do you not edit your question... better readable and understandable questions will get better answers

Comment: @Meiko We are modified our question .please guide to us.Give me any idea we will try to solve my probelm

Comment: did you get error messages... something in the error console in your browser?

Comment: @Meiko no we are not get any error

Comment: @Meiko we got this error "Can't find keyplane that supports type 5 for keyboard iPhone-Portrait-PhonePad; using 3561727473_Portrait_iPhone-Complex-Pad_Default"

Comment: no log, no alert - no output from the JavaScript code you posted? i would uncomment some code and look which line makes the trouble... without logs (or error messages) - and only with this slice of unformatted code in your questions it is not possible for me to help you. sorry :(

Comment: @PavanAlapati Did you able to see the Message in the COnsole that Db got Opened?